# Generic repository, nested class mapping

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4.1, nested-class

I'm trying to generate a Generic Repository. So far, so good. 
But I get the same error as somebody else posted before:
[Mapping to a nested class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583996/ef-4-1-code-first-data-mapping-problem)

The problem is that I am apparently trying to map a nested class. How can I fix this, so I do not map a nested class anymore?

EDIT:
That should not be the problem.

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Models
{
    public class MyContext :DbContext
    {

        public DbSet<ALBUM> Albums { get; set; }
        ...
}
}
```

where for example ALBUM:

```
[EdmEntityTypeAttribute(NamespaceName="MyDbModel", Name="ALBUM")]
    [Serializable()]
    [DataContractAttribute(IsReference=true)]
    public partial class ALBUM : EntityObject
```

Why is the class ALBUM not allowed to map?

Comment: You should *really* *really* post the error message you're getting, instead of making some sort of strange conclusion. Actually, I guess you should really read the error message first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the error message you're getting.

System.InvalidOperationException: The type 'ContactModels+Contact' was not mapped. Check that the type has not been explicitly excluded by using the Ignore method or NotMappedAttribute data annotation. Verify that the type was defined as a class, is not primitive, nested or generic, **and does not inherit from EntityObject.**

AND THIS is the class you're trying to map:

```
[EdmEntityTypeAttribute(NamespaceName="MyDbModel", Name="ALBUM")]
    [Serializable()]
    [DataContractAttribute(IsReference=true)]
    public partial class ALBUM : EntityObject
```

You're inherting from `EntityObject`. It says right there. You can't map it.

Answer (score 1):

Nested means you have a class inside a class, simply extract the nested class.

You probably have something like this:

```
public class SampleClass
{
      public class NestedClass
      {
      }
}
```

Change it to :

```
public class SampleClass
{}

public class NotNestedClass
{}
```

Comment: Thanks, in that case I don't have nested classes. See the update how my code works. So there should be another problem. Maybe the partial classes?